# can I show blur effect in view, even if its not on top of uitableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

for example if I have UIViewController , 50% is UIView, and 50% is UITableView.

can I show blur in UIView, of 25% part from uitableview ?

meaning, the UITableView is not behind the UIView, but tell the iOS to show the blur effect -like- is behind it ?

hope I'm clear here.

Comment: you have to format your question better because it's very confusing.To blur a subview you can try adding a `UIVisualEffectView` set it to a frame,give it a specific alpha and just add it to the subview.If this is what you meant..

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use a UIToolbar to give blur effect to a whole UIVIew/UITableView?

If that's what you're trying to do then the answer is yes, everything behind the UIToolbar will be blurred in-real-time.